# Snowflake Cursor throwing Error and executing as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a query to fetch all table names from a schema, append them to a query and then insert each row into a temporary table but I keep getting a weird error from Snowflake. This is the query I wrote:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_names;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_names (tname TEXT);

DECLARE
c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name 
              FROM information_schema.tables 
              WHERE table_schema = current_schema() 
              AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
              ORDER BY table_name;

BEGIN
    FOR record IN c1 DO
        INSERT INTO table_names 
           SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', record.table_name , true);
    END FOR;
END;
```

When I execute it I get this error:

`Error:'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 7 at position 4 : SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 48 (line 6) invalid identifier 'RECORD.TABLE_NAME' (line 6)`

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue is that you haven’t opened the cursor. If you look at the documentation for the FOR keyword it shows this. The documentation for cursors has a similar example but misses the open cursor statement - so I think it’s a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value of the cursor attribute to a regular variable and use it with your SQL:

```
DECLARE
c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name 
              FROM information_schema.tables 
              WHERE table_schema = current_schema() 
              AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
              ORDER BY table_name;
v_table_name VARCHAR;

BEGIN
    FOR record IN c1 DO
        v_table_name := record.table_name;
        INSERT INTO table_names 
           SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', :v_table_name , true);
    END FOR;
END;
```